# Drupal MailChimp Ecommerce Recover Abandoned Cart

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to integrate MailChimp to my Drupal 7 site. But I am facing some problems right now.

What I can do:

- I can subscribe new users to my MailChimp list.
- I can send order data to MailChimp when a customer completes their purchase.
- I can send **Welcome Message** campaign email.
- I can send **First Purchase** campaign email.
- I can send follow up mails for these campaign mails (for example; send mail after 1 hour if a subscriber receives First Purhcase email).

What I can **not** do:

- I can not send **Abandoned Cart** campaign emails.
- I can not show product info on ecommerce mails.
- I can not see Cart data when I make a POST request to usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/ecommerce/stores/{store_id}/carts

I would like to give more info if needed.
**edit:** fixed grammar
**edit:** I can see Cart data when I make a POST request to usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/ecommerce/stores/{store_id}/carts. To achieve that, I have just deleted cart data in my Drupal 7 commerce website. So it kind of worked like a soft restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue and fixed it.

For future readers;

The issue was that, MailChimp eCommerce module is not sending the checkout_url(path to the cart) out of the box. Although it is not required to sent checkout_url while POSTing, it is mandatory if you want to use Abandoned Cart email. In order to fix that problem, there are two patches that needs to applied.
[Patch #1](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/mailchimp_ecommerce-abandoned-carts-checkout-url-2903701-4.patch)
[Patch #2](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/mailchimp_ecommerce-store-missing-domain-2903707.patch)

[original link for the solution](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailchimp_ecommerce/issues/2903701)

Hope this helps someone :)